# wget escape special characters

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying to download the content of this webpage with wget:

```
https://bibliotheque-numerique.paris.fr/search.aspx?SC=DEFAULT#/Search/(query:(ForceSearch:!f,Page:0,PageRange:3,QueryString:'*:*',ResultSize:50,ScenarioCode:DEFAULT,ScenarioDisplayMode:display-standard,SearchLabel:'',SearchTerms:'',SortField:DateOfInsertion_sort,SortOrder:0,TemplateParams:(Scenario:'',Scope:VPCO,Size:!n,Source:'',Support:'')))
```

It doesn't work because of the special characters. I have tried to escape them with "\", but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The following works for me `wget "https://bibliotheque-numerique.paris.fr/search.aspx?SC=DEFAULT#/Search/(query:(ForceSearch:!f,Page:0,PageRange:3,QueryString:':',ResultSize:50,ScenarioCode:DEFAULT,ScenarioDisplayMode:display-standard,SearchLabel:'',SearchTerms:'',SortField:DateOfInsertion_sort,SortOrder:0,TemplateParams:(Scenario:'',Scope:VPCO,Size:!n,Source:'',Support:'')))"`

Comment: @GMichael It might depend on the shell. `zsh`, for example, interprets the `!` in the double-quoted string as some sort of history event, and fails to execute the command. (I suspect `tcsh` will do the same.)

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. I thought that `!` in the middle of a string is not interpreted as a history event

Comment: @GMichael That surprised me as well. It turns out that `bash` does the same thing, so I guess it's standard behavior for shells that implement csh-style history references. I wonder how the query worked for you without escaping `!`. What shell did you use?

Comment: @user4815162342 I used `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu. It does not support command history in my configuration. I tried in `bash ` and got the same error as OP

Answer (score 4):

Since the search query only uses single quotes, you can use double quotes to protect them from the shell. In addition, in zsh (and possibly other interactive shells) you need to escape the `!` character with a backslash, since `!` has meaning even inside double quotes. The result looks like this:

```
# use double quotes and escape "!"
wget "https://bibliotheque-numerique.paris.fr/search.aspx?SC=DEFAULT#/Search/(query:(ForceSearch:\!f,Page:0,PageRange:3,QueryString:':',ResultSize:50,ScenarioCode:DEFAULT,ScenarioDisplayMode:display-standard,SearchLabel:'',SearchTerms:'',SortField:DateOfInsertion_sort,SortOrder:0,TemplateParams:(Scenario:'',Scope:VPCO,Size:\!n,Source:'',Support:'')))"
```

To avoid such problems, you can use `wget -i` to specify an input file, where the URLs will be read line by line without interpretation of special characters (except for the newline character, which separates the lines). In conjunction with the `<<` operator, it allows specifying the URL without special quoting:

```
# use -i - to read from stdin, and the <<\ operator to feed
# the URL to Wget without having to quote it
wget -i - <<\.
https://bibliotheque-numerique.paris.fr/search.aspx?SC=DEFAULT#/Search/(query:(ForceSearch:!f,Page:0,PageRange:3,QueryString:':',ResultSize:50,ScenarioCode:DEFAULT,ScenarioDisplayMode:display-standard,SearchLabel:'',SearchTerms:'',SortField:DateOfInsertion_sort,SortOrder:0,TemplateParams:(Scenario:'',Scope:VPCO,Size:!n,Source:'',Support:'')))
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the URL in a command line variable as follows.

```
testUrl='http://www.example.com/1111?&nr=0.15859029847072859&edge=y&html5=y'
```

and then use it as follows:

```
wget $testUrl
```